# image processing (general)

Tags: c#, image-processing, stride

Sorry for dummy question but I am new in this and I could not find the answers.

1. What is image stride?
2. I am creating a buffer byte[] from Bitframe (there is no problem.) the bitframe width  is 1200, the bitframe height is 900. So (As I suspect) buffer must be 1200*900 = 108,0000. *But* buffer size is stride * height = 432,0000  (4 * 108,0000).

Stride calculates as `bitFrame.PixelWidth * ((bitFrame.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);`
Then I using `bitFrame.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0); //(byte[] pixels)` And I have the function of processing current pixel (that is a struct.)

```
struct pixel {
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};
```

And there is also pixel processing function pixel `processPixel(int x, int y)`. How could I use this function with my buffer ? I think it must be called somehow like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    processPixel(i, j); 
    // But how could I use this function with my byte[] buffer?
    // And what exactly in this buffer? 
    // (why stride*height = 4*width*height? cause there are 3 values for pixel RGB)
  }
}
```

Comment: I just googled "image stride" and the first hit looks quite good, is there anything specific you could not find there?

Comment: thank you. I just found this/ What about second part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Stride is the number of bytes per row of pixels regardless of how many of those pixels are part of the image, so you have to use stride in calculating which bytes to affect based on 2-D coordinates:

```
void processPixel(int x, int y)
{
    // This is if your image format is 4 bytes per pixel such as RGBA
    int startByteIndex = x * 4 + y * stride; 
}
```

**Edit:** I was too rushed -- answer updated based on comments.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your correct description.  It should be x * 4 + y * stride.

Comment: Thanks for the assitance/correction.  I was worried that I might not have been diligent enough about ensuring the correctness of the code, but I hoped someone would correct me if there was a problem.  Glad to see it worked out as I hoped.